# Creating X numbers of Applications and Application Pools in iis using a batch script

Tags: iis, batch-file

I currently have this batch file that allow me create an Application and Application Pool in IIS. it works, but it only creates just one Application and Application Pool.

this is my current script:

```
@echo ON
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion

REM "Content Source path" 
set arg1=%1

REM "Content destination path" 
set arg2=%2

REM "apps to setup" 
set arg3=%3

REM Split virt names and loop through it.
FOR /F "tokens=1* delims=," %%a in (%arg3%) do (

    set vir=%%a
    set pool=!vir!!poolname!

    REM CREATE APPLICATION  
    %systemroot%\system32\inetsrv\APPCMD add app /site.name:"Default Web Site" /path:/!vir! /physicalpath:"%arg2%"

    REM CREATE APP POOL
    %systemroot%\system32\inetsrv\appcmd add apppool /name:!pool! /managedPipelineMode:Integrated /processModel.identityType:ApplicationPoolIdentity /enable32BitAppOnWin64:false

    REM ASSIGN APP POOL TO APPLICATION
    %systemroot%\system32\inetsrv\appcmd set app /app.name:"Default Web Site/!vir!" /applicationPool:!pool!

):END Endlocal
```

install.bat "c:\source" "c:\target" "APP1,APP2,APP3"

Please can someone tell me what I'm doing wrong.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

try call your batch:

```
install.bat "c:\source" "c:\target" APP1,APP2,APP3
```

without double quotes surrounding `APP..`.
And set `args` in the batch:

```
set "arg3=%3,%4,%5"
```

Comment: Please have a look at `Microsoft's IIS Manual`. :)

Answer (score 2):

Issue 1: The `:END ENDLOCAL` should not follow the closing-parenthesis in the 'for %%a` loop. This generates a syntax error.

Issue 2: If the `:END ENDLOCAL` is moved to the next line, the `endlocal` is ineffective. Unlike Assembler, Batch does not execute "instructions" appearing after a label.

Issue 3: The `:END` label is superfluous. It is not used in the batch.

Issue 4: The `endlocal` is superfluous - reaching end-of-file closes any local environment operating in the same context.

Issue 5: assigning a variable using `%n` (n numeric) will INCLUDE the enclosing quotes in the value assigned. Use `%~n` to dispose of the enclosing quotes.

Issue 6: `FOR/F` is targeted against files. Whereas it will parse a quoted string as though it was an `echo %string%` instruction, that is but one line and hence your code will process only one (the number of "lines" encountered) time, assigning the first `,`-separated token to `%%a` and the remainder to `%%b` (not used)

What you need in this case is far simpler -

```
FOR %%a in (%arg3%) do (
```

Issue 7: the variable `poolname` is not established in this code. Unless it is assigned before the code is executed, `set pool=!vir!!poolname!` will set `pool` to `!vir!` which is itself equivalent to `%%a`. Given the arguments you've shown, and the changes I've flagged, then within your code, `!pool!==!vir!==%%a`